# How can I get old version of Julia DataFrames?

Tags: dataframe, julia

How can I get old version of Julia DataFrames? Now, DataFrames is 1.5.0. But I need 1.4.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
]add DataFrames@1.4.4
```

in project environment in which you need this version.

Answer (score 1):

1.4.4 should be available at [the old github release page](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/tree/v1.4.4).